# Android studio won't create SQLite table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have been getting error messages in the log saying that "columns" are not created whenever I try to insert a username and password. I need fresh sets of eyes to check my code! What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!!

This is the MainActivity:

```
package com.vogella.android.sqlitedatabase;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Initialaize stuff
    EditText editTextID;
    EditText editTextName;
    EditText editTextPassword;

    DatabaseManager dbManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Access corresponding edittext
        editTextID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextID);
        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        //Open database here
        dbManager = new DatabaseManager(this);

            try {
                dbManager.open();

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    public void btnInsert(View view) {

        dbManager.insert(editTextName.getText().toString(), editTextPassword.getText().toString());
    }

    public void btnFetch(View view) {

        Cursor cursor= dbManager.fetch();

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String ID= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.User_ID));
                String username = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.User_Name));
                String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.User_Pass));
                Log.i("DATABASE_TAG", "I have read ID : " + ID + "Username: " + "password: " + password);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    public void btnUpdate(View view) {
        dbManager.update(Long.parseLong(editTextID.getText().toString()), editTextName.getText().toString(), editTextPassword.getText().toString());
    }

    public void btnDelete(View view) {
        dbManager.delete(Long.parseLong(editTextID.getText().toString()));
    }
}
```

This is the DatabaseManager:

```
package com.vogella.android.sqlitedatabase;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import java.sql.SQLDataException;

public class DatabaseManager {

    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DatabaseManager(Context ctx){
        context= ctx;
    }

    //Initialize database instance
    public DatabaseManager open() throws SQLDataException {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        database= dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //Close database
    public void close(){
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public void insert (String username, String password){
        ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.User_Name, username);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.User_Pass, password);
        database.insert(DatabaseHelper.Database_Table, null, contentValues);
    }

    public Cursor fetch(){
        String [] columns = new String [] {DatabaseHelper.User_ID, DatabaseHelper.User_Name, DatabaseHelper.User_Pass};
        Cursor cursor= database.query(DatabaseHelper.Database_Table, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        if (cursor!=null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    public int update (long _id, String username, String password){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.User_Name, username);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.User_Pass, password);
        int ret= database.update(DatabaseHelper.Database_Table, contentValues, DatabaseHelper.User_ID+"="+_id,
                null);
        return ret;
    }

    public void delete(long _id){
        database.delete(DatabaseHelper.Database_Table, DatabaseHelper.User_ID+"="+_id, null);
    }
}
```

This is the DatabaseHelper:

```
package com.vogella.android.sqlitedatabase;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static final String Database_name= "MY_COMPANY.DB";
    static final int Database_version= 1;

    static final String Database_Table= "USERS";
    static final String User_ID= "_ID";
    static final String User_Name= "user_name";
    static final String User_Pass= "password";

    //Creating query for database
    private static final String CREATE_DB_QUERY= "CREATE TABLE " + Database_Table + " ( " + User_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + User_Name + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + User_Pass + " TEXT NOT NULL );";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, Database_name, null, Database_version);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

        db.execSQL(CREATE_DB_QUERY);

   }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ Database_Table);

    }
}
```

And these are the error messages I'm getting:

```
2022-02-24 15:03:11.249 13154-13154/com.vogella.android.sqlitedatabase E/SQLiteLog: (1) table USERS has no column named password
2022-02-24 15:03:11.261 13154-13154/com.vogella.android.sqlitedatabase E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting password=lkj user_name=testing
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table USERS has no column named password (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO USERS(password,user_name) VALUES (?,?)
```

Comment: Does the file "MY_COMPANY.DB" existing in your Apps database directory? (Use android studio "Device Explorer" to look for it). You might have created the file previously and because you have still `Database_version` set to `1` it won't go through the `onCreate` process again. (Or just increase your `Database_version`)

Comment: I didn't have that!! I just removed the .db and it worked! Thank you so much !!